# randomly selecting 100 companies data on s&p 500 companies

Tags: python, stock

I have been given three csv files one containing S & P 500 companies, the other two containing the data on their volumes and returns. how do i select 100 companies out of these 500 companies randomly in Python

```
from random import seed
from random import choice

seed(2)
numbers = [i for i in range(100)]

print(data)

for _ in range(50):
    selection = choice(numbers)
    print(selection)
```

Comment: Are your description and your code even vaguely related?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what the issue is? Are you stuck on reading from CSV or stuck on selecting random indices?

Comment: Unfortunately, stack overflow is not a code writing service. Please provide a [mcve] for the _specific_ issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Using random.choice() could lead to duplicate samples, because it is random sampling with replacement.

Try this:

Makes new list with a specified number of random elements from another list.

```py
from random import sample
numbers = [i for i in range(500)]
hundred_selected_numbers = sample(numbers, 100)
```

Comment: `random.sample` is the canonical answer here, I would be tempted to edit out alternate answers entirely - since they are slower and longer